# R how to add legend on googleVis geochart

Tags: r, legend, googlevis

I am using googleVis and I am wondering how I can be able to edit legend text. For instance, I have a map to visualize two variables using markers. The size of the marker is determined by one variable var1 and its color by the other var2. The generated plot is only showing legend for one variable only

```
map <- gvisGeoChart(df, locationvar = 'state',
                colorvar = 'var1', sizevar = 'var2',
                options = list(region = 'US',displayMode = 'markers'))
plot(map)
```

[image]

So how can I (1) add the second variable in legend (i.e the size legend) and (2) add legend titles?